# Twig - using macro from parent template

Tags: macros, import, twig

Lets say i have a simple macro in `macro.html.twig`:

```
{% macro simple_macro() %}
    <h1>Simple macro</h1>
{% endmacro %}
```

Heres template layout.html.twig:

```
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

And main file `content.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'layout' %}

{% from 'simple_macro' import simple_macro %}

{% block body %}
    {{ simple_macro() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Following code works, but i have many files like `content.html.twig` and i don't want to copy/paste `{% from 'simple_macro' import simple_macro %}` in a every single file. So i moved this line into `layout.html.twig`:

```
{% from 'simple_macro' import simple_macro %}

{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

but it throws error:

`The function "simple_macro" does not exist in "content".`

Here's my question:
Is it possible to import macros in parent template and use them in child templates?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Macros have to be imported in the specific file where you are using them, and this behaviour is by design to increase verbosity and readability of code - life wouldn't exactly become clearer if you could use tons of random tags in a template without a clear clue of where they're being defined.

Comment: This behavior is called inheritance. Also i know how to prepare good template tree and does not import tons of unnecessary tags. But thank you, that's the answer of my question.

Comment: It's not really inheritance - inheritance implies extending functionality with similar and/or related functionality. In a template engine most people would just use this to include an entire kitchen sink of magic functions into your core `master.twig` and have it done with in 500 other templates. In programming terms, that's not inheritance but akin to throwing your entire program in a single base class - which is just as bad practice. Similarly, in PHP/C++/C#/Java/etc extension also doesn't imply you get the `using`/`import` statements from the included class.

Answer (score -1):

It is indeed possible using `import`:

```
{% extends 'foo.html.twig' %}

{% import 'foo.html.twig' as foo %}

{% block content %}
    <div{{ foo.attributes(listAttributes) }}>
        {{ block('children') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You’re missing the point. The macro would have to be included in foo.html.twig, and you wouldn't have to import it again in the extended template.